# CORS POLICY EXPRESS

Tags: node.js, express, cors

I have this problem on my production server under express node.js :

"Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

But i have write that to test :

```
const allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {


    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    res.header('access-control-allow-credentials', true);

    return next();
}

app.use(allowCrossDomain)
```

Other example :

```
// CORS middleware
const allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {

    var allowedOrigins = ['http://127.0.0.1:9091', 'http://localhost:9091', 'http://localhost:9090'];
    var origin = req.headers.origin;

    if(allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) > -1){
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', origin);
    }

    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type,x-access-token');
    res.header('access-control-allow-credentials', true);

    return next();
}

app.use(allowCrossDomain)



// let static middleware do its job
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));


router.get('/me', function(req, res) {
  let token = req.headers['x-access-token'];
  if (!token) return res.status(401).send({ auth: false, message: 'No token provided.' });

  jwt.verify(token, config.secret, function(err, decoded) {
    if (err) return res.status(500).send({ auth: false, message: 'Failed to authenticate token.' });

    res.status(200).send(decoded);
  });
});
```

Comment: That error, was it for an OPTIONS request coming from a browser?

Comment: yes, my server test is on local and vueJS is on a different path (in wamp)

Comment: It seems like OPTIONS need to be added to the allowed methods. Try adding that and let me know if that works.

Comment: Hmm how do i do that ?
I add some code on the main post

Comment: I added an answer to show how to add `OPTIONS` as an allowed method. It's basically adding it to the existing methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

install `cors` and you wont be any problems
`const cors = require('cors');`
`app.use(cors());`
link on npm https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

Comment: How do i use this package to get the same things as my code on my first post ?

Comment: `options = {
"origin": "*",
"methods": "GET,POST",
"allowedHeaders": ["Origin", "X-Requested-With", "Content-Type", "Accept"],
"credentials": true
}`
then just insert options in method => `app.use(cors(options))`

Comment: you can read more about configuration on site npm https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#configuring-cors

Comment: Thank you !
Your solution worked !
Why yours and not the one above ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like likely `OPTIONS` request type is being blocked from a browser based request. Add `OPTIONS` to the `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` head as an allowed method:

```
// CORS middleware
const allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {

    var allowedOrigins = ['http://127.0.0.1:9091', 'http://localhost:9091', 'http://localhost:9090'];
    var origin = req.headers.origin;

    if(allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) > -1){
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', origin);
    }

    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'OPTIONS, GET, POST'); // added OPTIONS as an allowed method
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type,x-access-token');
    res.header('access-control-allow-credentials', true);

    return next();
}

app.use(allowCrossDomain)
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer...
But it do not work :( 
I have the same message.

Comment: thank you very much for your help but the solution was not working (I don't know why). The solution of "shuts13" worked.